# Changing text color on 2 sides of diagonal gradient line in html

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

Any idea on how to change text color for 2 parts of gradient line? For example here if I want the blue part of the text ('s', 'o' and a part of 'm') to be black?

```
.button{
   background: linear-gradient(140deg, #00C9FF 35%, transparent 35%);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe blend modes could help but other than that I don't think there is any pure CSS option for achieving this (unless you add a dupe element on top and style it differently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it wrapping the text in a `<p>` tag and setting a `linear-gradient` to this tag.

```css
button{
   background: linear-gradient(140deg, #00C9FF 35%, transparent 35%);
   color: white;
   font-size: 30px;
}

p{
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 50px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(130deg, red 65%, black 15%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button type="button"><p>some long text</p></button>
```