# Can we color a paragraph text(50%-50%) with 2 different colors only with CSS, without using any inline tags or any other scripting language?

Tags: html, css

Need to color a paragraph with 2 different colors in the ratio of 1:1 or 50%-50% text of the paragraph. We can not use any other tags,inline css or any other scripting or programming language. which syntax of CSS should I use.

I have tried pseudo classes like ::first-letter and ::first-line but we need to color the text in the 50%-50% ratio.

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831837/gradient-text-color

Answer (score 2):

I hacked this one

[Changing text color on 2 sides of diagonal gradient line in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020910/changing-text-color-on-2-sides-of-diagonal-gradient-line-in-html#)

```css
div {
  width: 290px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(190deg, red 50%, orange 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>This text needs to fill 100% to work</div>
```

Comment: Great sir this is excellent, but what if we need 50% of the text of the paragraph in one color while rest 50% text to be in another.

Comment: It was what I could find. You can change the black too